# How to resolve eclipse error as 'value' used with 'is_same' can not be resolved?

Tags: c++, eclipse, c++11

I have eclipse ide and linux platform ,inside eclipse i am using 'is_same' as :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
int main()
{
std::cout << std::is_same<int, int32_t>::value;
}
```

When i build it it throws error as 'Symbol value could not be resolved'.
I have done the c++11 related settings inside eclipse as:

```
 1)right click project> properties>C/C++ Build> Discovery Options select
 'Compiler invocation arguments' added -std=c++0x
```

So , now 'is_same' is being recognized but the 'value' is not getting resolved.
I have also added few settings inside

```
 c/c++ General>Path and Symbols selected symbol tag and added      
'__GXX_EXPERIMENTAL_CXX0X__ ' and left the value blank.
```

So, please help me what am i missing if compiler is able to find 'is_same' then why is it not able to resolve 'value'?

Comment: Have you tried with `-std=c++11`?

Comment: @101010 yes i have tried with -std=c++11 also but it still not able to resolve symbol value